# Change EC2 hostname via cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have fully automation to setup my infrastructure needs on aws with cloudformation. But I'm stuck to change hostname from default hostname ip-192.123.2.1 to something meaningful string name in the template.

When I do this manually its working but when I try to do with userdata on cloudformation template. It does not work. What am I missing in the template, wrong syntax, wrong usage?

First Attempt:

```
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      [....]
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: 
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash
            echo "preserve_hostname: true" >> /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
            hostnamectl set-hostname myserver.localdomain
            echo "HOSTNAME=myserver.localdomain" >> /etc/sysconfig/network
            echo "127.0.0.1 myserver.localdomain" >> /etc/hosts
```

Second Attempt:

```
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      [....]
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: 
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash
            sed -i '15s/false/true/g' /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
            hostnamectl set-hostname --static myserver.localdomain
            echo "127.0.0.1 myserver.localdomain" >> /etc/hosts
```

Third Attempt:

```
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      [....]
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: 
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash
            fqdn: myserver.localdomain
            runcmd:
             - echo "preserve_hostname: true" >> /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
```

Comment: It would be good idea to at least provide what OS are you using.

Comment: @Marcin ah sorry Debian linux 10 (buster edition)